# "No XLIFF language files were found." After updating to MAT 3.1

Tags: localization, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have a Windows Store project that I've been developing for quite some time. The Multilingual App Toolkit has been amazing so far. Recently I updated to version 3.1. Unfortunately, this caused the build process to not process my `.xlf` files that I've been using for a year now.

Based on [this entry](http://blog.giovannimodica.com/post/how-to-use-the-multilingual-app-toolkit-mat-in-a-portable-class-library-pcl-project) I took a look at my project file. The resources were defined similarly to how the blog entry suggested they *should* be. Similar to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <XliffResource Include="MultilingualResources\MyProject.WinRT_ar.xlf" />
    <XliffResource Include="MultilingualResources\MyProject.WinRT_bg-BG.xlf" />
    <XliffResource Include="MultilingualResources\MyProject.WinRT_ca-ES.xlf" />
    ...
```

I tried many things, including adding `<Generator>` tags. None of it seemed to be working. How can I get the project to see my `.xlf`s?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by ironically doing *exactly the opposite* of what is described in the article. I replaced the `<XliffResource>` tags with `<None>` tags. Like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="MultilingualResources\MyProject.WinRT_ar.xlf" />
    <None Include="MultilingualResources\MyProject.WinRT_bg-BG.xlf" />
    <None Include="MultilingualResources\MyProject.WinRT_ca-ES.xlf" />
    ...
```

The MAT is now working just as it was before. I have sent an email in to the MAT team to see if this is a bug, so this fix may change in the future. I will update this answer if necessary.